# Centre one element and one to the right

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get my div elements lined up as follows:

[image]

But currently it appears like this:

[image]

How would I resolve this issue, I'd like the `Member since June 2015` text to be centred and the icon to be positioned to the right.

I've mocked up a jsfiddle below which shows this.

**HTML**

```
<div class="profile-header">
  <div class="profile-rating">
    <i class="icon ion-star energized" ng-repeat="i in [1, 2, 3, 4]"></i><i class="icon ion-star dark" ng-repeat="i in [1]"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="ee">
    <div class="profile-join-date">Member since June 2015</div>
    <div class="ddd">&Theta;</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.profile-header {
  padding-top: 2em;
  padding-bottom: 1.75em;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.profile-name {
  padding-top: 0.75em;
  padding-bottom: 0.75em;
  font-size: 1.75em;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.profile-rating {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  padding-bottom: 0.75em;
}

.profile-join-date {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.ddd {
  float: right;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 2em;
  padding-right: 0.5em;
}

.profile-join-date {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.ee {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8ybz6z13/

Comment: try changing `.profile-join-date`'s `display` from `inline` to `inline-block`( https://jsfiddle.net/3bq3gt39/ )

Comment: if that's what you meant to achieve, tell me and I will put it as an answer

Comment: I'd like to centre the `Member since June 2015` text and position the `settings icon` to the right. Your solution doesn't do this :(

Comment: check [this one out](https://jsfiddle.net/z7vhq158/). I've set `.profile-join-date`'s `width` to `100%`, `.ee`'s `position` to `relative` and `.ddd`'s `position` to `absolute` (so it's relative to .ee yet floating above .profile-join-date)

Comment: You could always just use ::after and assign the gear icon to the CSS content property. Then you just have to use basic CSS positioning on the ::after pseudo class in order to position it exactly where you want. Then you dont have to worry about getting separate divs to align and retain that alignment on different viewports.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after

Comment: a question is does the post author want the text to be centered exactly in the center or can the text go to the left on smaller screens

Comment: @PawełZmarzły this works: https://jsfiddle.net/z7vhq158/

Comment: keep in mind that on smaller screens the gear may go above the text

Comment: Just add text-align:center to parent div: ee https://jsfiddle.net/8ybz6z13/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made few changes to the fiddle - my fork can be found at https://jsfiddle.net/z7vhq158/

I made it center the text exactly.

HTML (**no changes**):

```
<div class="profile-header">
  <div class="profile-rating">
    <i class="icon ion-star energized" ng-repeat="i in [1, 2, 3, 4]"></i><i class="icon ion-star dark" ng-repeat="i in [1]"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="ee">
    <div class="profile-join-date">Member since June 2015</div>
    <div class="ddd">&Theta;</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

Changes:

- changed `.profile-join-date`'s `display` to `inline-block` and set its `width` to `100%`
- made pseudo-overlay from the button by setting `.ddd`'s `position` to `absolute` with `right: 0; top: 0` and `.ee`'s (container's) `position` to `relative`

Full code:

```
.profile-header {
  padding-top: 2em;
  padding-bottom: 1.75em;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.profile-name {
  padding-top: 0.75em;
  padding-bottom: 0.75em;
  font-size: 1.75em;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.profile-rating {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  padding-bottom: 0.75em;
}

.profile-join-date {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.ddd {
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 2em;
  padding-right: 0.5em;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.ee {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
```

Please be aware it's not going to display correctly on smaller screens. IMO it's better to sacrifice exact text centering and make it's grid-like (see comments and other answers or make the button child of text element or something like this)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `display: table` on the parent div. On the childs use `display: table-cell`.

```css
.member-info {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.cell-center {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto; /* this centers the text */
  text-align: center; /* this centers the wrapped text */ 
}

.cell-right {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: right;
  width: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div id="member-info">
  <div class="cell-center">Member since June 2015</div>
  <div class="cell-right">&Theta;</div>
</div>
```

Please check [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-table) for browser support and known issues. For more details about CSS table model check the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#q17.0).

I have updated the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/48r9z74u/2/). Also I have tidy up your example. Please remember make always a [minimal, complete and verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.